# Windows 10 mouse pointer is stuck at the top left corner

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, touchpad

My mouse cursor jumps and gets stuck at the top left corner of the screen. What is the solution for this?

Windows 10, Sony VAIO

Comment: Do you have a Synaptics touchpad?  If yes, try touching it with two fingertips at once, the misbehavior then usually stops.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: What machine is this on? Give us some more details.

Comment: Is there a hair or dirt on the lens?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time this problem occurs with touchscreens laptops. Sometimes they have an touchscreen pen driver which is located in your HID-compliant drivers. Sometimes light can affect this driver which will cause the cursor to jump at a certain point on your screen. This can happen if the compliant pen driver has the same frequency as the light.

**So how to fix this problem?**

1. Press the Windows key
2. Search for 'device manager'
3. Click on Human Interface Devices
4. Click on HID-compliant pen
5. Click on the 'X' in the top toolbar menu to remove this driver or click on the arrow which is facing down to disable it.

Your touchscreen will still be working and the mouse won't jump and get stuck again.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your mouse gets stuck in the corner of the screen when you unfocus a full-screen application. This happens to me when I tab out of Project cars to go to the desktop. The mouse is ok for 10-20 seconds then gets stuck at the top left of my monitor. The only way to get the mouse moving again was to refocus back to Project cars. After much frustration, here is the fix.

1. Right-click on the windows icon to the right of windows search bar.
2. Click and open Device Manager.
3. Scroll down and click on the arrow next to "Mice and other pointing devices".
4. If you see 2 or more "HID-Compliant mouse" listed, Check the properties of both.
5. In my case I use a generic unbranded USB mouse, the other driver was listed as a Logitech mouse which I do not own.
6. I disabled the "Logitech Gaming Virtual Mouse" driver by right-clicking on the driver and selecting "Disable device".
7. Close device Manager. No need to restart.
8. No more mouse stuck in the corner of the screen.

I think the Logitech Gaming Software is the culprit in this case. I installed it as I use this software with my Logitech G29 Sim Wheel. If you have a Logitech mouse, try disabling the other mouse driver(s)

Let me know if this works for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

My AIRPODS were the problem! If you have AirPods and have them outside the case near your computer, they interfere somehow.

Once I put my AirPods back in the case...BOOM. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Click the Windows button again and again and after a few seconds your mouse cursor will start moving.  It may get stuck again so when it starts moving, just restart your laptop or Computer.